# I cannot get through my reacts or nodejs tutorials due to a throw error

Tags: node.js

I am very new to this and I cannot get past my tutorial for nodejs. I am getting stuck at the point where I need to run my js file from the root folder. I created the file in my root directory so do I need to create a new folder for my server.js file or can I add it to my already created project?

when I attempt to run the $node server.js I am being returned a quite lengthy error message that I cannot decipher:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/brianjohnson/nodejs-express-mysql/serever.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

am I missing modules?

can anyone lead me in the right direction to correct this

I tried installing modules like $npm install express@latest --save and running $npm audit

Comment: It looks like Node is expecting you to have a file titled `serever.js` (misspelled?) in the folder located at `/Users/brianjohnson/nodejs-express-mysql/`, but a file with this name does not exist there. Can you verify that this is the intended spelling and that this file exists in that folder? It could be that you have an import statement somewhere that is expecting `server.js`, and `serever.js` is messing things up.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are running the server.js from wrong directory.